# How to capture type argument of nested property and map it to something else

Tags: typescript, typescript2.8, conditional-types

I don't really know how to ask this question so I think the best way is with an example of what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have the following object:

```
const obj = {
  one: 'some string',
  two: new Set<string>(),
};
```

and now I want to write a function that takes in that object and converts the `Set`s to `Array`s of the same type.

Here's the untyped javascript implementation:

```js
const obj = {
  one: 'some string',
  two: new Set().add('one').add('two'),
};

function convertToArrays(objWithSets) {
  return Object.entries(objWithSets).reduce((objectWithArrays, [key, value]) => {
    if (value instanceof Set) {
      objectWithArrays[key] = Array.from(value);
    } else {
      objectWithArrays[key] = value;
    }
    return objectWithArrays;
  }, {});
}


console.log('converted', convertToArrays(obj));
```

**How can I properly type the above function?** To clarify: it can take in any object (not just the one, two example) and if it sees a `Set<T>`, it transforms that to an `Array<T>`.

I know it requires capturing the type of the inner `Set` (which is `string` in this case) and conditionally mapping that type to `Array<string>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah you mean if any key in the object refers to a Set, convert it to an Array.

Comment: @y2bd yes, my apologies 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix of mapped types and conditional types to do this:

```
type InnerSetToArray<T> = { 
    [P in keyof T]: 
        T[P] extends Set<infer U> 
            ? Array<U> 
            : T[P] 
};

type InnerSet = { one: number, two: Set<string>, three: Set<Function>, four: Date };

// InnerArray === { one: number, two: string[], three: Function[], four: Date }
type InnerArray = InnerSetToArray<InnerSet>;
```

*Edit: original, overly specific answer below:*

Here we go, essentially as you describe:

```
function convertToArrays<T extends { one: string, two: Set<any> }>(objWithSets: T):
    T extends { one: string, two: Set<infer U> }
        ? { one: string, two: Array<U> }
        : never {
  /* ... */
}

// typeof x === { one: string, two: number[] }
const x = convertToArrays({ one: "hello", two: new Set([1, 2, 3]) })
```

We allow it to initially be `Set<any>` just to serve as a typeguard, and then infer the actual type with the conditional. The conditional narrows to `never` on a match failure, which should be fine as the initial check theoretically guarantees the conditional will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Whoops, realized the TS2.7 example doesn't actually work; conditional types are required here.

Comment: You did answer my question but I actually meant to ask another . I meant for `{one: string; two: Set<T>}` to imply any object and if it encountered a `Set<T>` to convert that to `Array<T>`. I'll add a clarification

Comment: I've expanded my answer to handle the general case.